# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Can a HTTP adapter call another HTTP adapter on server-side?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am developing app on worklight 6.1 version for iPad and deployed single adapter which is having multiple procedure inside it. Now I am hitting adapter from client-side and getting response from server. Storing that response somewhere and passing back to the next adapter call for getting related data for that response.

```
function GetUSERRID(){
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'CORE_ADAPTER',
            procedure : 'GetUserRID',
            parameters : [ param1, param2 ]
        };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : GetUserRID,
        onFailure : function GetUserRIDFailure(response){ busyInd.hide();console.log("reponse   failure  "+response);},
    });

}

function GetUserRID(response){
    var rid = response.invocationResult.RID;
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'CORE_ADAPTER',
            procedure : 'GetUserRID_Details',
            parameters : [ rid ]
        };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : ShowDetailsForRID,
        onFailure : function GetUserRID_DetailsFailure(response){ busyInd.hide();console.log("reponse   failure  "+response);},
    });
}
```

In the above code I am making two adapter calls from client. From the first I am getting some data which I am again passing back to next adapter for getting related data.

Can I make a single adapter call on server and that adapter will call another adapter on server with required data as a parameter from first adapter response and process it and return data back to client?

Comment: Did you read the "Advanced adapter usage and mashup" training module? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development

Comment: Good. I've written it as an answer; if you conclude that it helped you, feel free to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the ["Advanced adapter usage and mashup" training module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development), which talks exactly about how to "chain adapter invocations".

An example project is available as well in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Same as client side just use

WL.Server.invokeProcedure(invocationData,options);

```
var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'ADAPTER_NAME',
        procedure : 'PROCEDURE_NAME',
        parameters : [param1,param2]
    };

WL.Server.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
    onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
    onFailure : getDataFailure,
});
```