# How to read Worklight http adapter parameters dynamic?

Tags: rest, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have created an HTTP adapter and invoked a RESTFul service successfully, with following configuration

> `<protocol>http</protocol>`
>   `<domain>localhost</domain>`
>   `<port>8080</port>`

However, I want to read these parameters from my own properties file. (Not from workligh.properties file).

How can I do this? Please help.
I am using Worklight 6.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you cannot change a JavaScript adapter's connectivity parameters during runtime.

Long answer is that you can define what those will be based on the environment you are test/using, via custom properties in worklight.properties and/or JNDI properties in your server.xml. For a detailed review of how this can be accomplished, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159260/1530814

Answer (score 0):

Please update protocol,domain and port on the worklight.properties

```
protocol=http
domain=localhost
port=8080
```

and use following syntax on the .xml file

```
<protocol>${protocol}</protocol>
<domain>${domain}</domain>
<port>${port}</port>
```

Comment: This will help only during deployment, not during runtime.